Why i don't have "To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style" while adding eslint to my project?
So I'm a new developer and I've encountered this problem while i do eslint --init it doesn't show the option "To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style"screenshot
I've disabled prettier just in case but didn't work

Formatting rules are deprecated in the latest version of ESLint. See this post.
Though they recommend using a formatter like Prettier instead, the rules are still available as a separate plugin: ESLint Stylistic.
